# Primitive roots of all primes of the form $p=24k-1$

Tags: number-theory

Let $p=24k-1 $ s.t $ k \in \Bbb{N}$ where p is a prime number.

Explain why neither 2 or 3 is a primitive root of p.

i couldn't really get anywhere with the general case so i started by taking a case k=1 then p =23 and showed that 2 and 3 are not primitive roots of it in hope that that would give me a hint for the general case but it didnt.

is p is prime then we have $ \phi (24k-1) = 24k-2 = 2(12k-1) $

I don't really have much, i tried playing around with a condition that shows 2 is a primitive root of prime but it also didnt lead anywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** show that both $2$ and $3$ are quadratic residues modulo $p=24k-1$, so they cannot be primitive root.

Comment: Im not entirely certain what that will do but i assumed $x^{2} \equiv 2 \mod 24k+1 $ is that what i am trying to solve? if they are a quadratic residue why must they not be primitive roots?

Comment: If $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, then $$a^{(p-1)/2} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$ so $a$ cannot be a primitive root.

Comment: i figured it out, was a good exercise i must say though for anyone else trying it dont use the def'n of quadratic residue its a really bad idea.